# Change onClick to onLoad

Tags: jquery, onclick, onload

I'm new to the whole jquery game but I found a great tut snippet that is just what I need, but I need the latter half to happen as the page loads, not when the button is clicked.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').show()
    $('#loading').hide();
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
    $('iframe').attr( "src", "http://www.apple.com/");
});
  });
```

So the action that would happen following a button click actually happens right as the page is loaded... no waiting for the button to be clicked. It's a simple thing, just don't know how to do it and really do not need to learn the in and outs of jQuery as this is the only time I need to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('iframe').load(function() {
      $('iframe').show()
      $('#loading').hide();

    });
    $('#loading').show();
    $('iframe').attr( "src", "http://www.apple.com/");

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('iframe').load(function() {
     $('iframe').show()
     $('#loading').hide();
   });

   $('#loading').show();
    $('iframe').attr( "src", "http://www.apple.com/");

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').show()
    $('iframe').attr( "src", "http://www.apple.com/");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you want $('#button').onclick(...) not $('#button').click(...)

The click function simulates and fires a click event.